# MySQL "Duplicate entry" error when inserting data despite unique constraint

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm facing a "Duplicate entry" error when trying to insert data into a MySQL table, even though the values being inserted are unique and should not violate any constraints. I have a unique constraint defined on a column, but the error persists. I'm unsure of what could be causing this issue. Can someone help me identify and resolve the problem?

Here's the code snippet that triggers the error:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, name, email)
VALUES (1, 'John Doe', 'johndoe@example.com');
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

I have verified that the `id` column is set as the primary key, and there is no existing record with an `id` of 1 in the `users` table. Furthermore, I have checked for any triggers or stored procedures that could be causing the issue, but none exist. What could be causing this error? Is there anything else I should check or modify in my code or table structure? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Suppose to insert without any error

Comment: Normally with a unique primary key, it is set automatically, so you don’t need to pass it. Have you tried running it omitting the Id in both the field and value sections?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`.

Comment: I'll side with mysql: if id is truly the primary key, then there is an existing row with id=1, otherwise you would not get an error message for duplicate key.

Comment: Since this is just a code snippet, the problem may be in the rest of the code, e.g. you may accidently run this query twice and/or insert another row with id 1, and then rollback your transaction after the error (so the successfully inserted row with id 1 gets rolled back too, so when you check, there is no row anymore). Maybe try to run the query alone and directly e.g. in mysql workbench and check if it happens too. As Shadow said: assume that MySQL is right. Figure out why (or where) there is a row, and not, if MySQL is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

edit  ID column , set it to auto-increment.

And when you insert data , leave the value of the ID EMPTY, the "auto-increment" option will automatically increase the value by 1 each time you add a new row data.

Answer (score 0):

I think MySQL remembers IDs even if they are deleted (not too sure). Anyway this should solve your problem:

```
create table users
(
    id int auto_increment,
    name varchar(150),
    email varchar(255) not null unique,
    primary key(id)
);

insert into users(id, name, email) values(null, 'John Doe', 'johndoe@example.com')
```